# Where are \left and \right defined?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

In order to define a new environment using `\left` and `\right`, I need to know how those macros are defined.

Unfortunately, both `\show\left` and `\show\right` return an error. My last resort was to scan latex.ltx for the definitions of `\left` and `\right`, to no avail.

Where are `\left` and `\right` defined?

Comment: with `\show` you don't get an error it just shows the definition (not very informative definition for primitives) `show` output is formatted very similar to error output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\left` and `\right` are TeX primitives.

If you write `\show\left`, you will obtain:

```
> \left=\left.
```